# CodeIgniter db->select() strange behavior

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want concat two fields with comma:

```
$this->db->select("CONCAT(nev,',',id_tanar)",false)->from("tanar");
```

And when I use `$this->db->get()` and after that `$this->db->last_query()`, it shows:

```
SELECT CONCAT(nev, ', ', id_tanar) FROM (`tanar`)
```

(check the plus `space` character near after comma)

How can I disable this behavior? I don't want extra space...

Comment: Can you please copy/paste the actual line as code igniter should not be doing this, and this is obviously not a copy/paste as `taner` is not quoted properly...

Comment: Sorry, this was my fault. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Delete space here (\system\database\DB_active_rec.php):

Line 1701: `$sql .= implode(', ', $this->ar_select);`

Comment: Hm. I think it's a bug, yes? Because my `','` is a constant string, and shouldn't change.