# Writing SQL Queries in Codeigniter 2.0

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have the following function that does not work and I'm having the hardest time trying to figure it out.  I'm 12 and just learning, so forgive me:

```
function get_answer() {
$answer = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(questions) FROM possible_quest WHERE questions='something'");              

return $answer;
}
```

When I run the following SQL query in phpmyadmin, it returns the expected result

```
SELECT COUNT(questions) FROM possible_quest WHERE questions='something'
```

How do I get this working in CodeIgniter using my function above?

The PHP error I get is

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: 4096
>   Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string

Answer (score 4):

Could be:

```
function get_answer() 
{
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(questions) AS count FROM possible_quest WHERE questions='something'");

$count =  $query->row(); // returns an object of the first row
return $count->count;
// OR
$count =  $query->row_array(); // returns an asociative array of the result
return $count['count'];
}
```

Another thing: if you want to pass 'something' as a variable, you can use parametrized query, like

```
 $sql = "SELECT COUNT(questions) AS count FROM possible_quest WHERE questions = ?";
 $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($something));
```

which has the benefit of escaping automatically your variable, so you don't worry about sql injections.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup to the count.

Heres what you need to do is

```
$answer = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(questions) as count FROM possible_quest WHERE questions='something'")->first_row()->count;

//$answer is now setup to be count
```

One line. Thats the beauty of CI

Comment: one lining is possibile due to php5, not CI's only. And being it so beautiful is arguable, as if the concatenation becomes longer it can be confusing, especially if you're just starting

Comment: This is correct as PHP5 lets you use OOP. Begs the question, what did CI do before PHP5?

Comment: I don't know, I suppose just didn't use concatenation :)

Comment: This was possible even with php4. In order to implement method chaining you should make each method of a class return an instance of itself (return $this).

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is related to the fact that `$this->db->query` returns a result object, so you cannot use `$answer` directly as a string.

I suggest that you use `print_r($answer)` to see what could be going wrong with your conversion of objects to strings, if you have such a function in your model.

Comment: $this->db->query() doesn't return an array of objects

Comment: Corrected. I was thinking of $this->db->query()->result().

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because

```
return $answer;
```

should be

```
return $answer->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use an Active Record with method chaining when possible:

```
public function getAnswer() {
    return 
        $this->db->
        select('id')->
        where('questions', 'something')->
        get('possible_quest')->row()->count
    ;
}
```

or

```
public function getAnswer() {
    return 
        $this->db->
        select('id')->
        from('possible_quest')->
        where('questions', 'something')->
        get()->row()->count
    ;
}
```

It's secure, easy to use, easy to understand and read. Don't listen to people saying that a single-line code is something good because a good code should be readable.

Comment: ActiveRecord isn't perfect, has many bugs!
In most cases works well but sometimes faults and you don't understand what's wrong :(

Comment: @uzsolt Could you give me an example?

Comment: Yes, of course :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927458/codeigniter-db-select-strange-behavior and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860441/codeigniter-activerecord-join-backticking and its bug reports: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/634 and https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/590 - I'm using CI some months (and PHP plus some months) but I found these bugs.

Comment: Thanks. I have used CI for almost 3 years and had never faced such problems with AR. Anyway AR is suitable for a vast majority of queries and from my point of view you exaggerate telling "has many bugs". ;)

Comment: Yes, maybe it was a little exaggerate but it's enough for me :( You didn't ever need similar queries so you didn't know about these errors, so you can say, almost bug-free. But I can't create my queries because of this so I can say, "many bugs" :)

Comment: @uzsolt: Hi, Sorry for the late interference. Check this url"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860441/codeigniter-activerecord-join-backticking" which you posted as bug in codeignitor active records. There i gave my answer. If anything wrong in this, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter has functions for building queries and returning the count:

```
function get_answer() {
  $this->db->from("possible_quest");
  $this->db->where("questions", "something");
  return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

NOTE: The name of the function 'get_answer' doesn't match what you're actually doing. It looks like you're getting a count of questions, not an answer, so you should name it to something that makes more sense, like 'get_question_count'.